# adding ternary operator in meta description in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am trying to add meta decription which is dynamic i am trying to use ternary operator here what am i doing wrong here

```
<meta name="description" content={ itm.htmlsummery ? ( dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: itm.htmlsummery }}):({itm.Summary})} />
```

i am trying to add meta decription which is dynamic i am trying to use ternary operator here what am i doing wrong here
id there is `htmlsummery` then i want to show `htmlsummery` else i want to show `Summary`

`htmlsummery` is stored in db with htmltags so inorder to remove those tags i use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: itm.htmlsummery }}`

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong here is rendering HTML inside an attribute. The value you pass to `content` should be a text (string), not HTML.

```
✅
<meta name="description" content={condition ? "text 1" : "text 2"} />
```

```
❌
<meta name="description" content={condition ? <p>text 1</p> : <p>text 2</p>} />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML#adding_an_author_and_description

And the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` doesn't remove the tags... it converts an string to HTML and output it (render it). If you want to convert something like `let content = "<p>value from db</p>"` to `content = "value form db"`, then you need to use a custom function for manipulating the string; the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is not used for this.